# Airflow - Tell DAG to skip processing the 2nd of each month

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I built a simple AirFlow pipeline that processes incoming historical information. Because of the nature of the data, there are massively higher volumes on the 2nd day of each month. On those days, I want to process the data in 10 minute increments: `*/10 * 2 * *`

The rest of the days, I want to process it normally, in 2 hour increments `'0 */2 * * *'`

How do I tell my "normal" DAG to skip processing the 2nd of each month?

The DAG itself is pretty simple:

```
dag = DAG(
dag_name,
catchup=True,
default_args=default_args,
schedule_interval=schedule_interval
)   


with dag:
    historical = HistoricalToS3Operator(
    task_id=dag_name + '_extract',
    model=HistoricalModel.INVOICES
    )



    redshift = S3ToRedshiftOperator(
        task_id=dag_name + '_load',
        load_type='upsert',
        type_check=False,
        primary_key=primary_key,
        distkey=distkey,
        sortkey=sortkey,
        incremental_key=incremental_key,
        data_type='json',
        dag=dag
        )
historical >> redshift
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow using python library croniter, that's why easy to explain using examples:

Try this one:

```
iter = croniter('0 0 1,3-31 * *', base)

In [27]: print(iter.get_next(datetime))
2010-02-26 00:00:00

In [28]: print(iter.get_next(datetime))
2010-02-27 00:00:00

In [29]: print(iter.get_next(datetime))
2010-02-28 00:00:00

In [30]: print(iter.get_next(datetime))
2010-03-01 00:00:00

In [31]: print(iter.get_next(datetime))
2010-03-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: so I can just define my schedule interval like: schedule_interval = croniter('0 0 1,3-31 * *', base) ??

Comment: `schedule_interval = "0 0 1,3-31 * *"`